# DFExecutorUserError when copying data to cosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am copying data from one Cosmosdb collection to another within the same account.
I am getting following exception

> {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to
> reason: Errors encountered in bulk update API execution. Number of
> failures corresponding to exception of type:
> java.lang.RuntimeException = 500; FAILURE: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Stored proc returned failure 404\n\tat
> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.bulkexecutor.internal.BatchUpdater$1.call(BatchUpdater.java:199)\n\tat
> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.bulkexecutor.internal.BatchUpdater$1.call(BatchUpdater.java:148)\n\tat
> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)\n\tat
> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)\n\tat
> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoo","Details":"Errors encountered in bulk
> update API execution. Number of failures corresponding to exception of
> type: java.lang.RuntimeException = 500; FAILURE:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Stored proc returned failure 404\n\tat
> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.bulkexecutor.internal.BatchUpdater$1.call(BatchUpdater.java:199)\n\tat
> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.bulkexecutor.internal.BatchUpdater$1.call(BatchUpdater.java:148)\n\tat
> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)\n\tat
> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)\n\tat
> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Threa"}

Comment: Can you provide your screenshot of Data Flow?

Comment: Unable to repro. It started to work after multiple retries.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the answer as per the comment by the original poster:

> It started to work after multiple retries.